# Sails authentication is allowing me to hit endpoints without any tokens...

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I followed this tutorial :

```
http://blog.cendekiapp.com/2015/04/02/add-authentication-in-sailsjs-api/
```

and when I want to run the app, it works fine when I run :

```
sails lift
```

But, if I try and hit endpoints via a rest client... it will return me data, without any kind of login being necessary...

I notice the comments, and people are having the same issue - my code is IDENTICAL to the one in the example, and is even built on top of the tutorial from part one (before the auth tutorial)

if I hit http://localhost:1337/user - it will return me all users, I am sure it needs to be checking for a token, which I would get via checking if I have one to submit, or go get one from the login controller, but I am not sure what I need to do. Anyone have any ideas? Or know straight up what is missing?

Comment: please post your policies.js content

Comment: I will do that this evening, as soon as I get back to the house - I am at the doctors right now! :(

Comment: Agree sounds like a policies issue. Also please post your routes config I've seen a few times people utilising "*" which has caused this issue.

Comment: I actually got this to work, there was an issue in my .policies file. I had followed the tutorial, and the tutorial used spaces areound the * in '*', (so it looked like this - ' * ' - which caused this error.

That said, now that I have fixed it, my company is dropping this approach and going with dropwizard! haha